Circles, projectile motion, and parabola

A projectile is thrown at an angle $\theta$ from $O\;(0,0)$ and reaches $R\;(R,0)$ given $R$ is the range of the projectile. A point $P$ is taken on its trajectory and is joined with $O\;(0,0)$ and $R\;(R,0)$ such that $\angle OPR=M$ (in degrees). Then find the range of $\theta$ in terms of $M$ so that angle $M$ can be formed in its trajectory, given $0<\theta<90$.

To explain my question let's say $M=90^\circ$. So here, we will have to find the range of $\theta$ so $90^\circ$ can be formed in its trajectory ($\angle OPR$).
I found this question in an Olympiad book and I can't find its solution anywhere, though the answer given there was $\tan^{-1}(2 \cot(M/2)) \le \theta<180-M$.

@DavidK here I have fixed the value of range R so that we can get different trajectory(paths) of projectile for different u and theta.         Meaning the projectile can have infinite h max with its range still being r or a finite h max but range still being R.    Thanks for your time if you have more ideas please let me know

I was apparently mistaken about the definition of range. Often, in real-world applications such as the specifications of a naval gun, "range" is a fixed quantity. But in the mathematics of projectiles, that kind of "range" is called maximum range. In any case, the name we choose for $R$ has no effect on the answer to the question.

Hi @DavidK I get your point but what I still don't get is why are you saying the word maximum range shouldn't it be simply range of the projectile

I was referring to how people use the word "range" when discussing projectiles in contexts other than math problems. For example, "The M1 75mm pack howitzer, with a range of 8,880 meters" doesn't mean that the gun could only fire a projectile to land 8,880 meters away. Rather, 8,880 meters was the maximum distance to the landing point, or the maximum range. But they don't say "maximum" because it is understood that of course you can hit closer targets too.

Sometimes real-life applications help to motivate a math problem, sometimes the language of the real-life application just gets in the way of the math. I think this is one of the "gets in the way" cases.

The first thing I would investigate would be to look at circles through $O$ and $R$ that also intersect the arc of the parabola between $O$ and $R$.
If $P$ is one of those points of intersection then $\angle OPR$ is an inscribed angle.
You should be able to relate the magnitude $M$ of the angle $\angle OPR$
to the radius of the circle.
I would consider the limiting cases of these circles (minimum and maximum radius)
to find the minimum and maximum values of $M$.
As a hint, one point I would look at would be the vertex of the parabola,
which is at the point $V\left(\frac R2,h\right)$ where $h$ is some function of $\theta$. (The formula of the function also involves the parameter $R$.)
This should lead to the minimum and maximum of $M$ as functions of $\theta$,
which you can invert to find the minimum and maximum of $\theta$ as functions of $M$.

Let's take $\theta$ as the initial launch angle (in degrees) of the projectile. Then, $\tan(\theta)$ is the initial slope of the projectile's path.
We also know that the projectile has a parabolic path that curves downward. This means that its derivative is a decreasing linear function which we'll call $g(x)$, and $g(0)=\tan(\theta)$.
Next, if the projectile's range is $r$, then we know that $g\left(\frac r2\right)=0$. This is because the projectile must start descending halfway through its flight in order to return to its original vertical position (ground level) at $x=r$. This information allows us to write the equation of $g(x)$:
$g(x)=\tan(\theta)-\frac{2\tan(\theta)}{r}x$
The antiderivative of $g(x)$ is the function of the projectile's path, which we'll call $f(x)$:
$f(x)=\tan(\theta)x-\frac{\tan(\theta)}{r}x^2$
Now that we have $f(x)$, we can visualize the graph and $\triangle OPR$:

The next step is to write an equation that tells us the value of $\angle OPR$. We can do this by dividing $\triangle OPR$ along its altitude to create two right triangles, which then allows us to use simple trigonometry to find the angle.

Now we can find $\angle OPR$ by adding together $\angle pPO$ and $\angle pPR$, where point $p$ lies on the $x$-axis directly underneath $P$.
$\angle OPR= \arctan\left(\frac{x}{f(x)}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{r-x}{f(x)}\right)$
This brings us to the most important step: finding the minimum and maximum possible values of $\angle OPR$. This is very important because if we know the minimum and maximum values of $\angle OPR$ for some value of $\theta$, then we can easily tell whether or not the angle $M$ can be inscribed in the parabola with that value of $\theta$. If $\min(\angle OPR) \le M \le \max(\angle OPR)$, then $M$ can be inscribed in the parabola, and the corresponding $\theta$ value is a solution. Then, solving the inequality for $\theta$ will give us the full range of $\theta$ values that allow angle $M$ to be inscribed.
Equation for the minimum possible value of $\angle OPR$
Just by observing the graph, we can intuitively tell that the minimum value of $\angle OPR$ occurs when point $P$ is at the vertex of the parabola $(x=\frac r2)$. We can represent this using the general formula of $\angle OPR$ that we had earlier, just replacing the $x$-variable with $\frac r2$ and simplifying:
$$\min(\angle OPR)= \arctan\left(\frac{\frac r2}{f\left(\frac r2\right)}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{r-\frac r2}{f\left(\frac r2\right)}\right) \tag{1}$$
$$\min(\angle OPR)= \arctan\left(\frac{\frac r2}{f\left(\frac r2\right)}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{\frac r2}{f\left(\frac r2\right)}\right) \tag{2}$$
$$\boxed{\min(\angle OPR)= \arctan\left(\frac{\frac r2}{f\left(\frac r2\right)}\right)\times 2} \tag{3}$$
Since $\min(\angle OPR)$ must be less than or equal to $M$, we get the inequality $\min(\angle OPR) \le M$.
Equation for the maximum possible value of $\angle OPR$
Looking at the graph again, we can tell that $\angle OPR$ should increase as point $P$ traces along the parabola and gets closer to point $O$ (or point $R$). Specifically, as $P$ gets closer to $O$, $\angle pPR$ approaches $90^\circ$. On the other hand, $\angle POp$ approaches $\theta$, which means $\angle pPO$ approaches $90-\theta$. Now that we have $\angle pPO$ and $\angle pPR$, we can add them together to get the maximum value of $\angle OPR$:
$$\max(OPR)=90+(90-\theta) \tag{1}$$
$$\boxed{\max(OPR)=180-\theta} \tag{2}$$
However, it's important to keep in mind that this is just the limit as $P$ approaches $O$'s position, not the true maximum angle (if $P$ reached $O$'s position, then the angles would become nonexistent). Therefore, we have to make sure to specify that $M<180-\theta$, not $M\le 180-\theta$.
Solving the inequalities for $\theta$
Now that we have the equations for $\min(\angle OPR)$ and $\max(\angle OPR)$, we can relate them to $M$ as inequalities, then solve for $\theta$.
Condition 1: The minimum value of $\angle OPR$ must be less than or equal to angle $M$.
$$\min(\angle OPR) \le M \tag{1}$$
$$\arctan\left(\frac{\frac r2}{f\left(\frac r2\right)}\right)\times 2 \le M \tag{2}$$
$$\arctan\left(\frac{\frac r2}{\tan(\theta)\left(\frac r2 \right)-\frac{\tan(\theta)}{r}\left(\frac r2 \right)^2}\right)\times 2 \le M \tag{3}$$
$$\arctan\left(\frac{\frac r2}{\tan(\theta)\left(\frac r2 \right)-\frac{\tan(\theta)}{r}\left(\frac r2 \right)^2}\right) \le \frac M2 \tag{4}$$
$$\frac{\frac r2}{\tan(\theta)\left(\frac r2 \right)-\frac{\tan(\theta)}{r}\left(\frac r2 \right)^2} \le \tan\left(\frac M2 \right) \tag{5}$$
$$\frac{\frac r2}{\tan(\theta) \left(\frac r2-\frac 1r\left(\frac r2 \right)^2\right)} \le \tan\left(\frac M2 \right) \tag{6}$$
$$\frac{\frac r2}{\tan(\theta) \left(\frac r4 \right)} \le \tan\left(\frac M2 \right) \tag{7}$$
$$\frac{2}{\tan(\theta)} \le \tan\left(\frac M2 \right) \tag{8}$$
$$\frac{2}{\tan\left(\frac M2 \right)} \le \tan(\theta) \tag{9}$$
$$\boxed{\arctan\left(2 \cot\left(\frac M2 \right)\right) \le \theta} \tag{10}$$
Condition 2: The angle $M$ must be less than the maximum value of $\angle OPR$.
$$M<\max(\angle OPR) \tag{1}$$
$$M<180-\theta \tag{2}$$
$$\boxed{\theta<180-M} \tag{3}$$
Now we put the two inequalities together to get the final range of $\theta$:
$$\boxed{\arctan\left(2 \cot\left(\frac M2 \right)\right) \le \theta < 180-M}$$
